# Assigning each column in a file as a variable to use in a function with a for loop

Tags: python, file, function, variables, for-loop

I'm trying to assign each column in a file (3 columns, 20+ rows) as a variable to use within a defined function. The function simply multiplies the three values from each column for each row. I have tried using a dictionary method as shown below but it doesn't work. The intended outcome is the for loop to run through each row with the function and print out a statement for each; for example if the first row is 8, 12, 9 - I want the function to multiply these together, for each row, then print out the value as a statement.

```
 60 def calculator(Col1, Col2, Col3):
---> 61     volume = Col1 * Col2 * Col3
 62     return volume
 63 import csv

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' 





def calculator(f1, f2, f3):
    volume = (f1) * (f2) * (f3) 
    return volume   
f1 = "Length"
f2 = "Height"
f3 = "Width"    
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("C:\file.csv", delimiter    = ',', dtype = str)
with open("C:\Users\Desktop\file.csv") as f:
    mydictionary={f1:[], f2:[], f3:[]}
    for row in f:
        mydictionary[f1].append(row[0]) 
        mydictionary[f2].append(row[1])
        mydictionary[f3].append(row[2])
        print row
        f1, f2, f3 = map(float, row)
    print 'The calculated value is' + ' ' + calculator(f1, f2, f3)
```

Comment: Can you fix the indent below your func? :)

Comment: If I add int(Column1) etc to the three, I get a "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ColumnName1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@StevenRumbalski originally identified the problem with your code and provided a solution but it has gone missing....

`f1`, `f2`, `f3` are strings that you defined earlier in the code.  You pass these strings to your function and it tries to multiply the strings to each other which throws a `TypeError`.

You create a dictionary with three items, one for each column. The dictionary values contain the value for each row for that column.  You never do anything with your dictionary.  I don't think that dictionary structure will help you achieve your goal of finding the product of the columns of each row.

Here is an alternative that will work with an indeterminate number of columns.

```
import csv, operator
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # row is a list of strings,
        # one item for each column:  row --> [c1, c2, c3, ...]
        print ' * '.join(row),
        # create a list of floats
        row = map(float, row)
        # multiply all items
        result = reduce(operator.mul, row)
        print '= ', result
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
Please consider data types (even in python).
Please try something like:

```
def calculator(col1,col2,col3):
    volume = (float(col1) * float(col2) * float(col3) )
    return volume
```

If it doesn't work please post the error message.
Regards,
d.

Comment: Hi, error received was: could not convert string to float: ColumnName1

Comment: Refering your note, you tried to cast the string 'ColumnName1' into float. Maybe it is the headline of your csv?